# Why is only part of cell top aligned?

Tags: html, css

I have markup looking something like this:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table.t_group {
                border: 2px solid black;
                margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
            }
   
            table.t_group > tbody > tr > td {
                vertical-align: top;
            }
        </style>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <table class="t_group" style="width:500px">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img height="24" widht="24"/> First cell
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Last cell
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

The key problem is vertical alignment of text in cells with an image. For whatever reason, it is aligned to bottom, but I expect it to be aligned to top.

Why does it happen this way? How to align text in cells with images to top?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You image is not aligned properly using `vertical-align` therefore the text next to it is at the baseline of your image

Use:

```
table img{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

***[jsBin playground](http://jsbin.com/xucaga/1/edit?html,css,js,output)***
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: Thank you! Could you please look into a follow up question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813517/why-cell-with-mixed-content-is-not-top-aligned) and recommend an article which describes these alignments as I cannot find something which makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to align the images as well – right now, image and text are sitting on one “line”, and with the image aligned to the baseline by default, this is the effect you’ll get.

```
img { vertical-align: top; }
```

This will fix it.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please look into a follow up question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813517/why-cell-with-mixed-content-is-not-top-aligned) and recommend an article which describes these alignments as I cannot find something which makes sense.