# Why cell with mixed content is not top aligned?

Tags: html, css

In the recent question ([Why is only part of cell top aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813403/why-only-part-of-cell-is-top-aligned)) I asked similar question.

When I applied its solution to my web site... I still have another problem:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table.t_group {
            border: 2px solid black;
            margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
        }

        table.t_group > tbody > tr > td,
        table.t_group > tbody > tr > td > img,
        table.t_group > tbody > tr > td > a {
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <table class="t_group" style="width:500px">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img height="24" widht="24"/> First cell
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a><img height="24" widht="24"/></a> 
                    <a>HREF_text1</a> (regular text, <a>HREF_text2</a>)
                </td>
                <td>
                    Last cell
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<body>
</html>
```

The middle cell contains "Regular" text which is still aligned to the bottom.

Why? How To fix?

P.S. Please also recommend where to read more on this matter. I fell damn asking these type of questions.

EDITED:

I see that solution to do:

```
table img{
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

would work,... but why? Don't understand how

table img is different from my table.t_group > tbody > tr > td > img

Comment: I can't recreate issue with HTML/CSS you have posted, post your real HTML, rather...

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/xkf0xLtp/)

Comment: About your question: https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Oriol: I have source code in question in a separate file and it is not aligning according to the problem description. Putting source code of real code... is hard, though you can look into it live: http://vfm-elita.com/tournament/2759

Comment: But now reading article referenced by nevermind I understand the problem... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With help of nevermind reading https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/ I got the problem.

What I needed is to add another 'internal stage':

table.t_group > tbody > tr > td > a > img

Or apply just "table img".

Thanks all!

Comment: and interestingly `table img` was the actual answer to yoru previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32813403/why-is-only-part-of-cell-top-aligned :)

Comment: Yes, but for me it was looking too generic and unreasonable, so I tried to find more specific solution. Didn't work, but I learned something new.